# How to save Image to a Database?

Tags: c#, winforms

I encounter this error when I'm trying to save my image into database.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Here's the design of my table:

[image]

I'm using Microsoft Server 2008.

Comment: it is the cause of the error?

Comment: well document, take another:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. The (understandable) confusion about the `Image` data type in SQL Server. This is actually just a large binary object (a BLOB in common parlance). In order to save an image (or anything else) in this column, you have to first convert it to a `byte[]`, then store that byte array in the column.
2. You're using the `Image` data type, which is deprecated. If you have control over this design, change it to use `varbinary(MAX)`. While the `Image` type is still in SQL Server 2008 R2, it will be removed from future versions at some point.

To get a `byte[]` representing the image, try this out:

```
byte[] data;

using(System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    data = stream.ToArray();
}
```

The `data` variable now contains the binary data of the image, and you can use that as your parameter value. There are additional steps you can take here (saving it in another format like JPEG, for example), but this should at least get you started.

When retrieving the data, it'll also come back as a `byte[]`, so you'll need to turn that into an image again.

```
byte[] data = ...;

Image image = Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(data));
```

Comment: @yonan2236: Can you be more specific...?

Comment: i got an error for this code: `image.Save(stream)` - has some invalid arguments

Comment: i got again another error: `String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated` Sorry, I can't make it work. My data type in my database server for image is varbinary(MAX). Right?

Comment: @yonan2236: Yes, `varbinary(MAX)`. Are you passing in values for `ProductId` or `FileName` that are larger than the fields? Both have a maximum length of 50, and I could easily see a file name being more than 50 characters.

Comment: yes! it's the filename causing that error : ) Thank you very much sir... Just one last question... When it comes to retrieval, do i have to convert the varbinary from server into image? so i can dispaly it in my application right?

Comment: @yonan2236: I'll post an edit that does that in just a moment.

Comment: Wish i can give another credit to you for that. Thanks again sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, there is no conversion from a GDI Image object to a byte array (which is what the SQL Server data column type Image really is). You need to convert your Image object into a byte array before adding it as a parameter.