# Retrieving a image from database to asp.net page using c#

Tags: c#

I am new to this functionality, our company projects are containing similar functionality but the store the image path with in the server and they retreive according to that. But I want to store the image as image type in database and I want show as it is in the Asp.net page(imagebox).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you want to show it to pass it client you can create specific method that will return an image and use this url in src for imagebox:

```
public ActionResult GetAvatar(int id) {
    using (var dbContainer = new MainDBContainer()) {
        return File(dbContainer.UserSet.First(p => p.Id == id).Image.Image,"image/png");
    }
}
```

Or you can use Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the image to a `binary format` that can be stored in a `SQL BLOB column` please [check this](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020929.asp) or [check that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852558/how-to-save-image-to-a-database) as well.